# Command prompt does not allow 'Makefile' to make / install mod_perl.so

Tags: windows-7, mod-perl, apache2.2

I had asked this question before, but deleted it when I was certain an IT expert had the answer. It's the same old story, but it's not a disaster if I am stuck using PHP5.
I downloaded and installed the mod_perl-2.0.9 folder in the Apache module folder. I already have a localhost running using Apache2.2, PHP 5.3, and MySQL 5.1.
I had this CLI prompt to do first:
C:\modperl_src> perl Makefile.PL MP_AP_PREFIX=\Path\to\Apache2
**Permission denied!**
If that had worked I had these last 3 steps to do:
C:\modperl_src> nmake
C:\modperl_src> nmake test
C:\modperl_src> nmake install
I have been told and found through searching various Permissions tables that Windows 7 has a System and a Creator class that rank above me (as an admin with full rights) and could be blocking the install. I made sure DEP was off during this attempt. I have no 'Trust' certificates to do the install. Any advice before I dump this attempt for good?

Comment: @arved. Thanks for the hints. They make sense. It could be Net 4.5 blocking me. This command would change crucial system variables, and I may need a Trust Certificate to make it work. I will ask some other IT senior engineers if there is a 'backdoor' way to do this. I intend to delete this question in 48 hours unless you think it is worth a bounty.

Comment: @arved. Why am I answering questions when no one has cast any up or down votes to my answers since 3-21-2016?

Comment: Because then it doesn't show up in the "Unanswered Questions" tab.